# How to concatenate server/service names within batch script sc query command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services, command-prompt

I have found a batch script that I am attempting to use here:

```
sc query "ServiceName" > ServiceReport.csv
```

For service name, I am using `"AdobeARMservice"` as a functioning example.

I save it as a .bat and later on, I will badge it within Windows Task Scheduler to run at an interval to create a constant report.

The problem is, I've read the documentation for `sc query` and it appears you can either list one specific service name or list all the services on the machine. Ideally, I want to list 10 specific service names that are propagated on all my machines in my team's environment.

Is there a way to concatenate service names so I can check on a selected and specific amount of services? I've tried the following:

```
sc query "AdobeARMservice" "aspnet_state" > ServiceListCount.csv

sc query "AdobeARMservice";"aspnet_state" > ServiceListCount.csv

sc query "AdobeARMservice; aspnet_state" > ServiceListCount.csv
```

and several other permutations of those initial 3 and still didn't work.

The second functional service name example is `"aspnet_state"`.

For anyone who is wondering: My goal here is to create a script that creates an hourly report of specific services to determine whether they are running and deemed "functional" within my environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could just provide each service inside a loop:

```bat
(For %%A In (
    AdobeARMservice
    aspnet_state
    AnOtherSvc
    "Random Serv"
) Do SC Query %%A)>ServicesOutput.txt
```

Comment: Would this also work if I just wanted to check all service names that start with a letter "a" for an example or had a specific naming convention like it started with "foobar_"?

Comment: No it wouldn't nor would it match your 10 specific service names requirment.